# Is wordpress better than Zend Framework 2 in seo?

Tags: php, wordpress, zend-framework, zend-framework2, seo

Recently, my friends say that wordpress is supported by google, so wordpress is better than Zend Framework 2 with seo. I am doubt about that things. Because I am only good at Zend Framework and PHP Core, buy he is good at both Zend Framework and Wordpress. Is he right or not?
I still belive that Zend Framework can be good as wordpress in seo term because Zend Framework can do functions wordpress have. But I don't know  about seo very much.
Please give me some tips in seo with Zend Framework.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: get new friends,what does "wordpress is supported by google" even mean ?

Comment: Your friend must be smoking the good stuff champ.

Comment: Whatever Wordpress does for SEO you can do in Zend, it will just take you longer is all. Because Wordpress is already built CMS with SEO plugins but Zend you'll have to build it all yourself. But you can make an identical end product in googles eyes in both (google only sees HTML/CSS etc and won't know the engine).

Answer (score 2):

Well since WordPress is used generally for making websites and not web applications I would say yes, WordPress  is better in SEO.